# how to find a text in database using c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to make search of a string in a data base in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695282/how-to-make-search-of-a-string-in-a-data-base-in-c-sharp)

I want to search for a name in details .. thats the code for search button

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString = Tyres.Properties.Settings.Default.Database1ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM table1 where Details like" + textBox1.Text, conn);
    SDA.Fill(dt);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

and this example of my application
[image: Click here to see the image]

I am getting the error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
```

Additional information: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'likeelie'.

I have tried this code to search for a integer(like Quantity) it works well for me :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString = Tyres.Properties.Settings.Default.Database1ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM table1 where Quantity like" + int.parse(textBox1.Text), conn);
    SDA.Fill(dt);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

so I need a help with the first code

Comment: You've asked basically the same question twice in a 3 hour span. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695282/how-to-make-search-of-a-string-in-a-data-base-in-c-sharp. Don't do that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you need to add a space in your SQL statement, you are just appending the value of `textBox1.Text` without a space, so the value of `textBox.Text` is becoming one word with `like`.

```
SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM table1 where Details like " + textBox1.Text, conn);
```

Comment: I would also recommend using SqlParameters [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbw6zyha(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: now i got another probleme :

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Invalid column name 'Audi'.

Comment: @user1951045 you should post another question to get that.  Not sure how you'd get an invalid column name from what you've posted.  It is possible that whatever you are providing through `textBox1` is the source of the issue.  Dynamically built SQL can be tricky, and if the input isn't sanitized they allow SQL Injection Attacks, so store procedures are preferred.

Comment: He gets that error because he puts a plain unquoted string in his SQL. So his input it treated like a column name.