# how to make search of a string in a data base in c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, facebook-c#-sdk, c#-2.0

This is the code that is used to make the search

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionString = Tyre.Properties.Settings.Default.Database1ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM table1 where Nom like " + textBox1.Text, conn);
        SDA.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
```

and im getting this error

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Invalid column name 'elie'.

thats a exemple of my application :
[image]
[Click here to see the image](http://i50.tinypic.com/opag60.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, your code is wide open to [SQL Injection](http://xkcd.com/327/).  You allow the user to insert any data he wants including

> ; DROP TABLE table1

To fix the immediate issue surround the item to be matched with single quotes and % signs:

```
"SELECT * FROM table1 where Nom like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'"
```

However, you *absolutely* should look into using a [parameterized query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468425/how-do-parameterized-queries-help-against-sql-injection).

Comment: thx bro it works well ... and im using this programe for my owen garage and its not connect to internet ...